# Using logical operators for variable initialization

Tags: php, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

If I want to initialize variables according to a specific condition, I can use conditional statements (`if`/`else`), but what if I write them like this?

```
5 !== 10 && $fruit = 'Apple' AND $color = 'Green';
```

The above is equivalent to the following:

```
if(5 !== 10){
  $fruit = 'Apple';
  $color = 'Green';
}
```

I would like to ask if using the one-line code instead of conditionals affects performance. Is it “valid” to write code like this?

Comment: Forget performance..... just pray that the person who has to maintain code like `5 !== 10 && $fruit = 'Apple' AND $color = 'Green';` isn't armed with a large axe

Comment: Don't be fancy with the code unless no one else in the universe has to look at it. If I had to maintain that, it would be the first thing to go.

Comment: If I had to maintain it, I'd go looking for an axe

Comment: Any reasoned comments?

Comment: @PhilipSorokin - READABILITY OF CODE is a reasoned comment. The behaviour of your code is completely non-intuitive, highly confusing, and susceptible to misinterpretation

Comment: If you want to know whether it's more performant, then test it and see..... but any performance benefit one way or the other will be negligeable; and don't expect compliments on your cleverness

Comment: However it's shorter and I can write it in one line.

Comment: You can write a standard `if` in one line; and shorter means you get to type fewer keystrokes, and your file is a few bytes smaller..... is that really such a big benefit compared with the fact that 99 out of 100 developers who read that code will have no understanding or what it does, and you'll probably have forgotten yourself in 6-months time

Comment: I've tested the variants. This code in one line is slower than conditional statements, but the difference is marked when a loop has a million iterations.

Answer (score 1):

While it works, you should consider that it's confusing to write it that way.

```
if(5 !== 10 && $fruit = 'Apple' AND $color = 'Green')
```

If i were to find that in my code base I would assume it was a typo because it's a fairly common typo to use `=` instead of `==`. Your assignments should be inside a bracketed section of code so it's unambiguous what you're trying to do.

Also, consider that `5 !== 10` is always `true` and you're mixing `AND` and `&&`. Consistency is important

Comment: Sorry, but you don't understand my question. Read it again, please!

Comment: @PhilipSorokin - so your question is "is it valid to write code that is horrendously unintuitive and that nobody will understand?" Machavity has actually answered your question "Is it "valid" to write like this?"

Comment: @PhilipSorokin I don't think there's any performance gains either way. You're not using any functions, which are the most common performance hit.